# How to run the TensorArray operation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

I want to evaluate the output of the TensorArray operation created by tf.TensorArray:

```
ta = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=2)

with tf.Session():
    ta_output=tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("TensorArray:0")
    print(ta_output.eval())
```

But I got the following error:

> InternalError: ndarray was 1 bytes but TF_Tensor was 134 bytes

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray?version=stable#stack) has detailed API documentation of the `TensorArray` class.

Before reading from the `TensorArray` object, you need to write at least one value to the it, using the `write()` method. Since you applied the tag `tensorflow2.0` on your question, I'll write the example in the TensorFlow 2.0 API, which is simpler and doesn't involve a Session object:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

ta = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=2)

ta.write(tf.constant(0),
         tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]], dtype=tf.float32))
ta.write(tf.constant(1),
         tf.constant([[-1, -2], [-3, -4]], dtype=tf.float32))

print(ta.stack())
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.